# Find all areas accessible to pedestrians with overpass

Tags: overpass-turbo

I'm trying to find all areas in London that are accessible by foot. I'm using overpass.

To be more precise, I would like to find all areas that are accessible by foot, except the roads where cars can go. Side walks are ok for example, but not the roads. Parks are ok. Buildings are not ok.

So far I have this query:

```
[out:json];
area[name="London"]->.searchArea;
(
  way(area.searchArea)["highway"="footway"];
  relation(area.searchArea)["highway"="footway"];
  way(area.searchArea)["highway"="pedestrian"];
  relation(area.searchArea)["highway"="pedestrian"];
  way(area.searchArea)["highway"="path"];
  relation(area.searchArea)["highway"="path"];
  way(area.searchArea)["leisure"="park"];
  relation(area.searchArea)["leisure"="park"];
);
out geom;
```

Is it possible to do better?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly

```
    [out:json];
    area[name="London"]->.searchArea;
    way(area.searchArea)[leisure=park];
    map_to_area->.park;
    (
     way(area.park)["highway"="footway"];
     way(area.park)["highway"="pedestrian"];
     way(area.park)["highway"="path"];  
    );
    out geom;
```